# Recursive functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function which splits the list in n-1 ways. After splitting I want to perform operations on each item of a split in a recursive way. I am not able to figure out how to go about this recursion as I am new to Haskel and was not able to understand how values can be used in Haskell

```
recur(list)= do [splitAt n list | n <- [1..((length list)-1)]]
                print say each first element of split( say [1,2] it should print [1] )
                recur(second element of list)
```

I wanted to know how to use the output of split and acrry on with next steps since Haskell we cant use variable declaration and use that variable.

Comment: So, you want to map a function over the output of `splitAt`?

Comment: Ok. First, do notation is related with monads. It is not design to be an imperative interface for haskell in general. So as an advice, forget it exists until you learn how to think functional. Your problem can be solve using function `map` and `inits` from `Data.List` library. Give it a try and come back if you can't solve it

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you written a recursive function on lists before?  In Haskell?  If not, what Haskell code have you written that might be a starting point?  (Non-recursive functions on lists?  Functions using `case`?  Functions on `Int`?)

Answer (score 0):

First write a function about what you want to do for a single list. For the simplicity, I am assuming that you want the first element of the list in string format. But this could be any function.

```
getFirstElement :: [a] -> String
getFirstEement [] = ""
getFirstElement (x:xs) = show x
```

Now you want to run this on list of list and combine them. You can write another function for it. What this will do is get the first element of all the lists and combine them

```
combineList :: [[a]] -> String
combineList [] = ""
combineList (x:xs) = getFirstElement x ++ <any separator if needed> ++ combineList xs
```

The above is using very basic of recursion and pattern matching. The last line of combinelist can be also written using fold function.

On further note, there is something called as "Applicative Functors" which exists with purpose "sequence computations and combine their results".